# Handle child routes (lazy loading)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

My project has different layouts depending on child routes.
For testing purpose I created only a module that should handle is own layout for all the sub-routes; that one is called secure and it will keep the features for the logged in user.

Said that, secure.component will have his own layout and the router-outlet for all the routes declared/imported in secure-routing.module

At the same time some components inside the secure folder (like test) could have a module and a routing-module if needed for nested routes; Otherwise will be just normal components.

```
src/
└── app/
    ├── views/
    │   └── secure/
    │       ├── test/
    │       │   ├── test-routing.module.ts
    │       │   ├── test.component.css
    │       │   ├── test.component.html
    │       │   ├── test.component.spec.ts
    │       │   ├── test.component.ts
    │       │   └── test.module.ts
    │       ├── secure-routing.module.ts
    │       ├── secure.component.css
    │       ├── secure.component.html
    │       ├── secure.component.spec.ts
    │       ├── secure.component.ts
    │       └── secure.module.ts
    ├── app-routing.module.ts
    ├── app.component.css
    ├── app.component.html
    ├── app.component.spec.ts
    ├── app.component.ts
    └── app.module.ts
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./views/secure/secure.module').then(m => m.SecureModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

secure-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SecureComponent } from './secure.component';

const routes: Routes = [

{ path: '', component: SecureComponent, children: [
  { path: 'test', loadChildren: () => import('./test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule) }
]}

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SecureRoutingModule { }
```

test-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: TestComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TestRoutingModule { }
```

Anything works right now, but at the same time as you could guess it loads the secure.component as soon as I hit the domain. I would like to load secure.component only when test route is called and without use the module name (secure) inside the Url.

**StackBlitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pfta1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fsecure%2Fsecure.module.ts

Comment: In which module have you declared your `secure.component.ts`

Comment: In secure.module.ts

Comment: Okay, because the example of your doesn't include the `declarations` array of that module

Comment: @Batajus I've added a stackblitz url. Thanks for your reply